# Entendendo os documentos de um web service SOAP

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, xsd

Estou trabalhando com um sistema que oferece integração através de *web service*, mais precisamente SOAP.

Ele me fornece algumas URLs, que, pelo que eu entendi, **dão acesso, descrevem e documentam todo o sistema**.

São elas:

- http://localhost/services/Assets?wsdl
- http://localhost/services/Assets?xsd=assets.xsd
- http://localhost/services/Assets?xsd=common.xsd

A documentação mostra que o arquivo WSDL pode ser importado diretamente na solução do Visual Studio, o que, mais uma vez, pelo que eu entendi, gera várias classes que fazem interface com o serviço.

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar essas três URLs (e somente elas) para compreender o serviço e poder utilizá-lo no programa, sem recorrer a outros documentos externos.

E, se for, como traduzir os elementos contidos nestes XML's em métodos em C#.

Trechos do WSDL:

```
<wsdl:message name="GetReservationsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="types:GetReservations">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="credentialsHeader" element="types:UserCredentials">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>


<wsdl:message name="CreateSubclipRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="types:CreateSubclip">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="credentialsHeader" element="types:UserCredentials">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>


<wsdl:message name="GetCustomUserAttributesResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="types:GetCustomUserAttributesResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
```

---

```
<wsdl:portType name="AssetsPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="AddReservation">
        <wsdl:documentation> Adds a reservation </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:AddReservationRequest"> </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:AddReservationResponse"> </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AssetsFault" message="tns:AssetsFault"> </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="AddFileMobs">
        <wsdl:documentation> Adds one or more file </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:AddFileMobsRequest"> </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:AddFileMobsResponse"> </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AssetsFault" message="tns:AssetsFault"> </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>


    <wsdl:operation name="CreateFolder">
        <wsdl:documentation> Creates a new folder </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:CreateFolderRequest"> </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:CreateFolderResponse"> </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AssetsFault" message="tns:AssetsFault"> </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>


    <wsdl:operation name="Search">
        <wsdl:documentation> Search for assets </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:SearchRequest"> </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:SearchResponse"> </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AssetsFault" message="tns:AssetsFault"> </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

---

```
<wsdl:operation name="AddReservation">
    <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:header message="tns:AddReservationRequest" use="literal"
          part="credentialsHeader"> </soap:header>
        <soap:body use="literal" parts="body"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault name="AssetsFault">
        <soap:fault name="AssetsFault" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>


<wsdl:operation name="AddFileMobs">
    <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:header message="tns:AddFileMobsRequest" use="literal"
          part="credentialsHeader"> </soap:header>
        <soap:body use="literal" parts="body"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault name="AssetsFault">
        <soap:fault name="AssetsFault" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
```

---

Trechos do `assets.xsd`:

```
<xsd:element type="tns:AddReservationType" name="AddReservation"/>
<xsd:complexType name="AddReservationType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation> Parameters for the AddReservation operation.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element type="tns:URIListType" name="FolderURIs"/>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="TimeToExpireInSeconds"/>
        <xsd:element type="tns:ExtensionType" name="Extension" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:any minOccurs="0" processContents="lax" namespace="##other"
          maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element type="tns:AddReservationResponseType" name="AddReservationResponse"/>
<xsd:complexType name="AddReservationResponseType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation> The response from the AddReservation operation.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element type="tns:ErrorListType" name="Errors" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element type="tns:ExtensionType" name="Extension" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:any minOccurs="0" processContents="lax" namespace="##other"
          maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

---

Trecho do `common.xsd`:

```
<xsd:complexType name="AssetDescriptionType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation> A pairing of an URI representing an
          asset along with a set of attributes describing it.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="URI" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Attributes" type="tns:AttributeListType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Extension" type="tns:ExtensionType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"
          namespace="##other"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

---

O que foi gerado ao importar o WSDL para o Visual Studio:

[image: Print da Tela do Visual Studio]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tradução do WSDL se dá da seguinte forma:

- Tags `<wsdl:operation>` são traduzidas como métodos que podem ser chamados. Elas possuem, normalmente, dois componentes: `<wsdl:input>` e `<wsdl:output>`, que enunciam as estruturas de dados de entrada e saída que, por sua vez, são Tags do tipo `<wsdl:message>`;
- Tags `<wsdl:message>` são traduzidas como o corpo dos métodos que podem ser chamados, e que, por sua vez, são compostos por Tags do tipo `<wsdl:element>`;
- Tags `<wsdl:element>` são traduzidas como conjuntos de dados, que podem ser das Tags tipos `<wsdl:complexType>` ou `<wsdl:sequence>`;
- Tags `<wsdl:complexType>` são traduzidas como objetos complexos de entrada ou retorno, formadas por Tags do tipo `<wsdl:sequence>`;
- Tags `<wsdl:sequence>` são traduzidas como argumentos, que podem ser parâmetros de entrada ou de retorno. Normalmente um `<wsdl:complexType>` contém um `<wsdl:sequence>`;

[Isso é o resumo do resumo disso aqui](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl).

Vou pegar um exemplo do `assets.xsd`: `AddReservation`. Ele é um método. Está expresso aqui:

```
<wsdl:operation name="AddReservation">
```

Ou seja, ele pode ser chamado assim:

```
new InterplayWSDemo().AddReservation(/* Coloque os parâmetros aqui */);
```

A descrição do que ele aceita como argumentos está aqui, mas o IntelliSense faz esse trabalho pra você.

```
<xsd:element type="tns:AddReservationType" name="AddReservation"/>
```

Ou seja, `AddReservation` é o corpo de um método que aceita como parâmetro `AddReservationType`, que é complexo e possui alguns parâmetros:

```
<xsd:complexType name="AddReservationType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation> Parameters for the AddReservation operation.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element type="tns:URIListType" name="FolderURIs"/>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="TimeToExpireInSeconds"/>
        <xsd:element type="tns:ExtensionType" name="Extension" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:any minOccurs="0" processContents="lax" namespace="##other"
          maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Da mesma forma, você pode trazer informações do Web Service assim (exemplo):

```
var pesquisa = new InterplayWSDemo().Search(/* Parâmetros de pesquisa conforme SearchRequest */);
```

Answer (score 0):

na sua solução, em References, clica com o botão direito, em seguinda Add Web Reference... , informa o endereço: "http://localhost/services/Assets?wsdl" (localhost) o serviço está no seu computador local ? verifique o endereço. 
Após adicionar a referencia web, será gerado a classe do webservice com suas propriedades e métodos, bem como outras classes dos tipos de objetos que estão especificados no wsdl